# Binding type for a non-overriden virtual function

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, overriding, dynamic-binding, static-binding

> Consider the case where a `virtual function` in base class is `not
>   overriden` in the derived class. Then using a `base class pointer to a
>   derived class object`the virtual function is invoked.

I understand that the function invocation will be resolved to the function in the base class during compile-time.

**Question**

Since the function is not overriden in the derived class, will the function call be bound to the function implementation during compile-time or will it still delay the binding until run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it will be resolved at compile time.
Most of the modern day compilers are smart enough to resolve dynamic dispatch at compilation time if there is enough credible information for them to decide so.
In this case since no overriding function is provided in the Derived class a smart compiler should be able to resolve the function call at compilation time statically.

Comment: Als : Resolution and Binding are different I believe. Could you correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: For that you will have to tell me how they are different.

Comment: Als : I believe, the virtual function call will be `resolved` to base class function based on the type of pointer during compile time and virtual function call be `bound` to function implementation based on type of object at run-time.

Comment: Als : In other words, If a function call is resolved, it can still be bound later. But if a function call is bound, it is bound for ever. So if a function call is bound at compile time, it cannot be bound at run-time. But if a function call is resolved at compile time, it can be bound statically or dynamically.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: Matching a function call with the correct function definition is called *Binding*. If this happens at compile time it is called as *Static binding* & if it happens at run-time it is called *Dynamic Binding*. A Modern day compiler is smart enough to resolve conclusively, that an virtual function call can be *bound* to only a particular definition at compile-time.During, such situations the compiler applies this optimization and binds the virtual function call even at compile time.Normally, this would happen by dynamic dispatch but yes compilers can optimize it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7020/discussion-between-linuxpenseur-and-als)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to guess the implementation at compile time the compiler must know the type of the pointed to object... for example

```
MyBaseClass *p = new MyDerivedClass;
p->foo();
```

In the above a compiler **should** be smart enough to guess the type of the pointed-to object and the dispatching (assuming the compiler is using the VMT solution for late binding) should require no VMT lookup even if the method is virtual.

However for example in the following

```
void doit(MyBaseClass *p)
{
    p->foo();
    ...
}
```

the code for `doit` cannot know the type of the object pointed to and therefore the call will require a VMT lookup. Note that the C++ language has been designed so that compilers can work one compilation unit at a time, therefore there is no way the compiler can know that there is for example only one derived type in your program (the source code of another module could define a different derived class, even in a local unnamed namespace, where the function is overridden).

Of course the function `doit` could end up being **inlined** by the compiler and so a specific **call site** invoking `doit` could indeed require no lookup if the type can be inferred. But if the `doit` function is publically visible (e.g. it's not in the unnamed namespace or a static free function) then the machine code generated for it will include a VMT lookup when called from other complation units.

Note that in all this discussion about when a lookup is needed or not is totally irrelevant if the virtual function has been overridden or not. The reason is that if a virtual function has not been overridden and the dispatching is implemented with VMTs then simply the derived class VMT will have in that slot the address of the base implementation.

In other words what happens is that `p->foo()` is compiled as either

```
 p->__VMT__[__FOO_VMT_SLOT_NUMBER__](p);  // Dynamic dispatch
```

or

```
 __DERIVED_FOO_IMPLEMENTATION__(p); // Type known at compile time
```

where `__DERIVED_FOO_IMPLEMENTATION__` is the function pointer stored in the VMT and it may be equal to the address of the base implementation or not depending on if the function has been overridden in the derived class.

Comment: Note all this is regardless of whether the virtual function is overridden or not.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: True. I added a paragraph and I hope now is clearer.